# Parse Store Tutorial Error

Tags: ios, xcode, class, parse-platform

I am trying to just get the ParseStore example up and running, I follow all the steps on

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseStore

But whenever I try to run the app after installing everything (Step 3 of Get Your App up and Running) the app fails saying 'Property className not found on object of type 'PFProductViewController''. Below is the code that is giving me the error:

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]) {
        self.className = @"Item";
        [self.tableView registerClass:[PFProductTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ParseProduct"];
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The sample project you mentioned around 2 years old and looks outdated (obviously). The property should now be `parseClassName`, not `className`